# Replacing Main Fragment from its Child Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5dDM.jpg)

I'm trying to replace `MainFragment` with other `Fragment` from `ChildFragment` of `MainFragment`. I using this part of code:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    fragment = MainFragment2.class.newInstance();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
                    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Problem is, `MainFragment` get's destroyed and replacing is successful, but problem is `Child` of `MainFragment` never gets destroyed and child methods(destroy, pause, stop..) never called(I need those methods). They remain in memory and when getting between `Activities` in App `OnResume()` method of child fragment gets called. Strange. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Create interface :

```
interface MainNavigaton {

     void replaceFragment();
 }
```

on the main Activity

```
class Activity exteds... implements MainNavigation
      public void replaceFragment() {
          //Replace fragment here.
      }
```

all childs that used this activity :

```
  private MainNavigation mainNav;
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
        mainNav = (MainNavigation) context;
   }
```

replace the fragment where you want.

```
action.onClickListner(new View.OnCLickListneer() {
        mainNav.replaceFragment();
    }
```

Comment: Why would this approach destroy child but calling replace from child don't?